# Beyond Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Let $f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3... $ be a Schwarz function then by lemma $|a_1|\leq 1 $.But what is known about the higher coefficients?

For example ; what can be said about $ max [a_1+a_2]$ ? Is there a method for 
solving such problems?
Thanks ..

Comment: What is a Schwarz function? A holomorphic $f\colon \mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ with $f(0) = 0$, or are there further constraints?

Comment: exactly,, no further constraints..

Comment: The Cauchy estimates give you $\lvert a_n\rvert \leqslant 1$ for all $n$. Not sure whether much can be said about $a_k + a_m$ for $k\neq m$.